# Disable mounting to `$HOME/.gvfs`

Tags: debian, gvfs

I am using Debian Wheezy with Xfce and Thunar.  Thunar (and other similer managers) enables e.g. connecting to SSH server using SFTP address like `sftp://mysvr/` and browsing it like a local folder.  I normally access my remote box via command line, but occasionally I appreciate this GUI sugar.

However, in default configuration, this has a pretty annoying downside: File systems accessed this way are automatically mounted under folder `$HOME/.gvfs`, which creates quite a nightmare for tasks that involve traversing through home folder (typically dotfile searching, or analyzing disk space usage issues).

[GNOME 2.2 RNs](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/2.22/#sect%3agvfs-gio) say:

> GVFS also offers a FUSE mountpoint in ~/.gvfs/ so that GVFS mounts
>   *can be exposed to legacy applications* using standard POSIX IO.

So I guess it's possible to turn this off (I assume by legacy they don't mean Nautilus and the likes).

However, I can't seem to find any information on how to do it.  Any pointers?

Comment: The `-x` option to `du` will solve your analyzing disk space usage problem.

Comment: This question is probably outdated, now, since exactly these issues were addressed by moving the GVFS mount point to `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs`, which typically locates it on a path outside of `$HOME` such as `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`. That should be in use on all current systems which support Gvfs/Gio. `$HOME/.gvfs` is a legacy path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gvfsd(1) states:

```
ENVIRONMENT
       GVFS_DISABLE_FUSE
           If this environment variable is set, gvfsd will not start the fuse
           filesystem.
```

So if you configure your display manager or `~/.profile` to set this variable it should work.

On the other hand most unix utilities have switches to disable recursion into other filesystems (mostly `-x`, for find it's `-xdev`)

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost embarrassed I did not know about this `-x` switch.

Comment: Also, before I get to test this, wouldn't this disable the whole feature (using FTPS in managers directly)?

Comment: The variable should only disable `~/.gfvs`. Access via GIO should still work. Or do you mean `-x`? Then I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: No, you understood correctly.  I see it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Finally made it work, thanks.  Just one more question:  Where did you get the manual?  It's not on my box, and I can't even find any official documentation...

Comment: On my archlinux box the `gvfs` package contains a bunch of manpages. (Look at the bottom of https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gvfs/files/)